# how to forward udp packets over tcp (udptunnel)

Tags: tcp, udp

how to use "udptunnel" so that i will be able to send and receive udp packets over tcp
probably with an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You start udptunnel on two PCs in different networks and connect them as decribed here: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~lennox/udptunnel/ with an example: http://wiki.leipzig.freifunk.net/Udptunnel

Comment: I know this post is really old, but just for reference, be aware of this quote:    
"For multicast, UDPTunnel turns off packet loopback, as it has no way to distinguish its own packets it sent out from packets genuinely arriving on the multicast group. This means that if you are tunneling traffic from or to a multicast group, both ends of UDPTunnel must be run on different hosts than any member of the group. (In general, the only way to distinguish looped packets from packets genuinely received from other applications on the local host is with application-layer labeling, as RTP does.)"

Comment: This is a very old post but I figured my comment could be relevant. I have recently created an open source program very similar to udptunnel except that mine is written in C++. Here is the GitHub page: [DatagramTunneler](https://github.com/MarkoPaul0/DatagramTunneler)