# Is there a way to forward UDP traffic over TCP?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I have a program that only serves under UDP. My router supports port forwarding, but only for TCP.

I want something to listen on a TCP port, and then forward it to a UDP port. Then I give the other party another script to listen on a local UDP port and forward it to me using the TCP port.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UDP to TCP - Ngrok TCP => UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208690/convert-udp-to-tcp-ngrok-tcp-udp), [how to forward udp packets over tcp (udptunnel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566208/how-to-forward-udp-packets-over-tcp-udptunnel). Or just use socat which can translate between a variety of protocols.